# Drupal 7 admin/config/people/accounts not displaying correctly. Cannot restrict User Account Creation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to limit the ability for user accounts to be created. My host has noticed spam activity on my account and has suggested that it is being generated by accessing the user account creation script directly.

When I try to access that feature in Drupal 7, the Setting tab doesn't render correctly. Fields and Display tabs function correctly.

[Screen Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3IMI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your host is right about the script being accessed directly, then your site might be hacked.

Since you also have problems with rendering of the settings tab, I would execute these steps in this order:

- Follow the instructions for updating Drupal, starting with backup of
  the database and the files:
  https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/updating-your-drupal-site/update-procedure-minor-version-change
- Set secure permissions for files and folders: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

The second step alone might help stopping the user creation by direct access to the script, but it will not get back the original settings tab.

Comment: I updated to 7.5. That solved the Settings Tab not rendering fully. I was able to set the Account Creation permissions to Only Admin. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeChorvat good to hear. I guess the version you updated to was 7.50 or 7.51. A long time ago there was an old version called 7.05 but there is no 7.5 what I know of.

Answer (score 0):

In back-end go to `Configuration -> People -> Account settings`. There is a section `Registration and cancellation` and `Who can register` radio buttons group where you can forbid anonymous user create account. If that's already set well and people are still registering then it really is possible that your site has been hacked.